# Word to describe the structure of a paper

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

In a paper, I need to mention the commonly-used “introduction, main part, conclusion” structure.

Is there a (single) word for describing this structure? It seems odd to write out “‘introduction, main part, conclusion’ structure” all the time.

Example sentence:

> - Sometimes papers with a strong investigative aspect don’t follow the “introduction, main part, conclusion” structure.
> - Sometimes papers with a strong investigative aspect don’t follow the __________ structure.

Comment: I've corrected spellings and the like. Is there a reason why a word like *tripartite* (of three parts) wouldn't work? If you don't like it, please [edit the question](/posts/507191/edit) to say why. Actually, please edit the question to include what words you have already looked up and found and why you don't like them.

Comment: @Andrew leach, because the middle part can be tripartite itself, requiring "fivefold"?

Comment: But I have to wonder, how do the papers deviate? Arguments can be structured to any degree of complexity, which either happens in the main part, or is omitted if the argument is known method that just has to be named. What area of research do you want to talk about? In many ways, a paper that needs to introduce a method, because it does not repeat the existing methodology, simply deviates from the methodology, and the structure of the report, article, survey, or whatever you have in mind, necessarily deviates.

Comment: @vectory The question does say "commonly-used". I think you may be overthinking it. I'm almost minded to suggest [*sonata form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonata_form)...

Comment: @AndrewLeach *sonata form* is a strong metaphor, indeed. But I was rather pointing out that the only way to deviate from three partition is *X* (?) if e.g. fivefoldness can be surmised under threepartition. I suppose OP already went with three partite, so there is no reason to be meta and criticize this sketch of a statement attempting to work out its meaning. I thought it was a neat opportunity to discuss structure for a sec. Even more off-topic let me note that *Ger *Einfall* "idea [sudden]" (cp "one fell swoop?) contrasts in pun with *Zweifel* "doubt" (second guess).

Comment: Those three things *are* the structure. of a paper Or, they make it up. So, I don't understand what's wrong with the word **structure** itself. Or, in your example sentence, *normal*.

Comment: I would describe a structure of paper as origami.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of wanting to point out exceptions that are not necessarily bad, the single adjective to describe the structure to which you refer is 'conventional'.

There are very strong arguments for departing from the convention of leaving readers waiting to the end of a long paper to find out what your conclusions were, so it would be as well, in your context, to avoid words that imply that such a structure is 'normal' or 'preferred'.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nova.edu/tutoring-testing/study-resources/forms/steps-to-a-basic-essay.pdf

A basic essay format/structure,which consists of three main parts: introduction, body, and conclusion.